# Can we enable Salesforce Functions in Developer Edition Org?

Tags: salesforce-functions

We already have a development edition org where we have been creating versions for a managed released package and deploying on production orgs.
Now we would like to use Salesforce Functions. But when we open Setup > Functions then it does not allow me to enable:

[image]

Please guide me that how to enable and use Functions for our future released versions?

Any help would be appreciated.

Thanks

Answer (score 6):

Even though Functions can't be enabled in a Developer Edition Org, you can Develop Functions using the local development experience, connected to a Dev org without using a license.

You can take a look at the tutorial I published here: [Getting Started with Salesforce Functions Locally. No License Required!](https://developer.salesforce.com/blogs/2021/11/getting-started-with-salesforce-functions-locally-no-license-required)

Comment: Thanks for your response. It sounds great that we can build it without a license. But can we deliver our app that is using functions to the customers through the released managed package?

Comment: No, we don't support managed packages yet.

Answer (score 4):

A Salesforce Functions license is required to enable Functions for your DevHub org. You need to contact your Salesforce account representative for steps to acquire the license. Salesforce is also planning an open-signup, time-limited Functions trial that will be available shortly.

Read the developer blog here: https://developer.salesforce.com/blogs/2021/10/salesforce-functions-is-generally-available

Comment: Thank you for your quick response. 
But I have a developer edition org with no DevHub Org enabled on it. 
And now I can't enable DevHub now because it says that I have managed the released package created so I can't do it now.
So what should be the solution for me now ?

Comment: You need to wait till further announcement when this feature is going to be available in developer org.

Comment: Not sure why the original post is getting down voted. I wanted to start exploring functions this morning and had the same confusion. And the  docs make it seem like you should be able to set up in a Developer Edition.  

https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/platform/functions/guide/configure_your_org.html

Answer (score 1):

You mentioned wanting to use Functions for a managed released package. Currently Functions are not packageable so you won't be able to use them in your managed package. (I can't find a source to link, but this limitation has been confirmed to me by product managers in Slack.)

As has been answered by others, you also can't enable them in a developer org. You can signup for a 30 day trial of a functions enabled org at https://functions.salesforce.com/signups. There are limited resources for the trial, so they are asking for only one trial per organization.

Comment: Thanks for the response. But my question is that if we cant deliver functions to customers through managed released package then what is the purpose of having functions in salesforce? Anyone would use functions for customers that would eventually go to the production org through managed released package.

Comment: Larger Salesforce customers have a need for Functions without needing to package it. I know the goal is to eventually package it, but for now it is not possible.